# Bitrix CMS, how to get cached data based on GET parameter in template of standart component?

Tags: caching, components, bitrix

I'm working with a component bitrix:catalog (which is standard one) and faced an issue. I want to add some extra GET parameters to switch view mode. I think there is no need to rewrite whole component to make such switcher, so I added extra keys in result_modifier in a way similar to:

`$this->__component->arResultCacheKeys = array_merge($this->__component->arResultCacheKeys, array('key1', "key2"));`

Earlier in the same result_modifier I perform adding those extra keys in `$arResult['key1']` etc. They seem to be correctly saved, but only for current inquiry such as `?view=list` or `view=card`, that means only one variable value is saved and it does not react on changing of GET parameter. Is there simple and correct way to make that component to cache and to output data based on GET variable? The only idea which came to my mind is to rewrite component by adding extra parameter and checking of GET, but I think there must more simple and correct solution to make in via template. Human Readable Links are turned on. And I want to have auto-cash being turned on as well. If I turn it off it starts working as planned.
One of possible solutions is to rewrite it cache by `SetTemplateCachedData` but it still seems to me rough and incorrect way for such simple task.

Bitrix masters please help me to find correct solution, google can't help at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use standard `bitrix:catalog` component, you may be use standart `bitrix:catalog.section`. In that `component.php` used standart component cache.
That means you can describe additional parametr in you custom `.parameters.php`, and set it in `bitrix:catalog.section` params.
Standart component cache set cacheId based on arParams.
So you include component should look like this:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section",
    "",
    array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD"],
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => $arParams["ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER"],
         ....
         ....
        "NEW_ADDITIONAL_GET_PARAMS"=> $_GET['view']
    ),
    $component
);
```

Of course better way somethink like

```
"NEW_ADDITIONAL_GET_PARAMS"=> (in_array($_GET['view'],array('list','card'))?$_GET['view']:'list')
```

But may be you need just set right catalog params: `SEF_MODE` `SEF_FOLDER` `SEF_URL_TEMPLATES`

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work. I also tried to add ResultCacheKeys template, and tried to add them via result modifier, still no luck. I believe there is some sort of cache problem in that site, I asked Bitrix support team to perform a check. As I know cache depends on keys of $arParams which is sent to a component via IncludeComponent, .parameters.php is used for editor parameters mostly